# How can I get a set of field values in groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

```
class Book {
  String title
}

def book = new Book(title: 'title1')
def book = new Book(title: 'title2')
def book = new Book(title: 'title3')
```

How can I get the set of titles? Something like `titleSet = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']`

I thought maybe something like `def titleSet = Book.findTitles();` would work but I can't find anything like that.

I know I could do:

```
def books = Book.list()
def titleSet
for(def book : books)
  titleSet.add(book.title)
```

But I'm looking for a groovier way.

Comment: `Book.all*.title as Set`. I think you can even remove the spread operator. `Book.all.title as Set` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes through all the books for their title and creates a Set instead of a List.

```
Book.all.title as Set
```

UPDATE
The above will fetch all Book instances which might be heavy if you only need `title`. You can also try using criteria or HQL to get only list of titles.

```
def titleSet = Book.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    projections {
        property('title')
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this select 'title' column alone when it hits DB? or fetches all columns but filters for 'title'?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Set titleSet = books*.title
```

Or

```
Set titleSet = books.collect { it.title }
```